# How can I find whether SQL Server is installed in a system on a network by using the IP address?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

How can I check whether SQL Server is installed in a system on a network?

I have to find it using IP address. Is this possible?

How to achieve it in c# code?

Comment: Do you have rights to run WMI code on the servers? Have any remote rights to read registry?

Answer (score 1):

In general SQL Server listens on port 1433:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

so if you find that this port is open there is a good chance (but not certain) that SQL Server is installed on that machine and is accessible.

You can check that this port is open by opening a socket to it: see the Socket class (doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) for details.

However, it's also possible to install SQL Server in many other modes where it is not accessible through this port. It's also possible to have this port open (and responsive) from other programs.

It's worth bearing in mind that best practice for securing a server accessible over the Internet would have the SQL Server on a non-standard port, no access to WMI, and (ideally) the server locked down to only open its port to the TCP/IP addresses of known white-listed clients. So in general: there is no way to do this scan that will *always* work. (Just as well, if you think about it...)

Comment: This port may never be used: I know shops where named instances are used which never use 1433. Also, 1434 may be blocked to port must be known in advance. Or SQL Server could be stopped. You typically need to read the registry or use WMI to find out

Comment: There are good reasons why one should never expose SQL Server to the outside world on port 1433 - so its frequently moved.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use WMI.

Here's how to detect if SQL Server is installed using WMI: [FAQ: Detecting SQL Server 2005 using WMI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/07/29/682254.aspx) (works for 2005, should be easy to adapt for other versions).

To connect to a remote computer using WMI, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Of course WMI must be installed, accessible, etc.